# WCF interoperability binding for duplex communication?

Tags: wcf, web-services, binding

I have a wcf sevice and silverlight client.
My contract has **callbacks** and therefore I implement **PollingDuplexHttpBinding**.

Now, I want connect to wcf service from java or c++ code. What binding should I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basicHttpBinding is the easiest for interop, but it won't support callbacks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx

Comment: tnx for the answer Matt. I  can't use basicHttpbinding. In my case wsDualHttpBinding is just one solution

Answer (score 1):

Not to pile on to the answer but my experience has shown that if your integration stack (Java, C++, whatever) supports the WS* bindings (i.e. WSHttp, WSDualHttp, WSFedHttp), they end up giving you a lot of bang for your buck. You can then use MTOM for message compression, support transactions should you choose to do so, and use more advanced security options. I've found that the major Java app servers play really well with the WS* bindings. For other COTS products, I usually finding myself adding things to the default Basic binding or removing things from the default WS* bindings to achieve compatibility.